# Getting results from each method within a delegate

Tags: c#, linq, delegates, func

I'm using a delegate to hold a few methods that test a value and return a true/false result. After learning that a call to a delegate will only return the result of the last method in the delegate, I'm unsure of how to proceed.

**I'd like to receive either the list of results from all the method calls in a delegate or if any of the calls returned true.**

First I tried enumerating over the delegate with a foreach, which didn't work. I had to pull the methods out beforehand like so

```
System.Delegate[] methods = int_testers.GetInvocationList();

// Methods in int_testers returns true when a condition is met by the input value
```

Then enumerate with dynamic invokes on each member within 'methods'

```
foreach (var item in ds) {
    if ((bool)item.DynamicInvoke(4))
        return true;
}
```

However, I've read that DynamicInvoke is much slower (order of magnitude or more) than Invoke which is a trade off I'm not willing to make.

The alternative so far I've found is to have a list of `Func<int,bool>` and enumerate over those,

```
List<Func<int,bool>> methods = ....; // Add the methods into the list

foreach (var method in methods) {
    if(method(4)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

While this works, it seems like an issue delegates were made to solve. So, finally, **is there a way to get a list of results from a delegate without simulating a delegate by hand?**

This is essentially using the results of a `map` function in functional terms but I don't have enough C# experience to bring that idea nicely to what I'm doing.

I looked into LINQ a little for this and it seems it could work with the second method I've outlined though I can't seem to use LINQ with delegates in this case.

Comment: Hey, please don't assume things without asking. This is for a library where the user will provide methods for the delegate/list of methods and my code will need to use that data before making taking it's own actions then returning to the users code.

Comment: Thank you, Predicate looks promising!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Predicate<T>` instead of delegate, and LINQ's `Any()` instead of a for loop:

```
var methods = new List<Predicate<T>>();

// add methods to list

return methods.Any(x => x(4));
```